# Submit only file input on change to server and ignore other inputs until submit form is pressed

Tags: html, ajax, forms, input

I have a form like this

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" onchange="uploadFile()" name="username">
    <textarea name="description"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="upload">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want when a user `selects a file` to automatically `upload` the file instead of the when the user clicks the `submit` button

trying to upload this on change event does show a post request, but the files are not in the request.

**Question:**
Can an individual input be submitted to the server without the other field inclusion via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It should be possible.

Heres an example:

```
uploadFile() {
    let formData = new FormData(); // Create FromData object
    let form = document.querySelector('form'); // Get the form element
    formData.append( 'upload', form.upload.files[0] ) // Add your file with the name upload to the formData.
    await fetch('yourPostTarget.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
    }); // Send the file to your server using ajax
}
```

Other fixes:

- You should probably add an action to your form.
- The onchange function to upload the file should probably be in the file input not the text input.

Comment: What if I have different endpoint in the server to handle both differently, say I have an endpoint to handle the file upload and I have an endpoint to handle input submissions. will this work as expected?

Comment: Yes, to make this work the endpoints for a fileupload and the rest of the form submission should be seperate, since the other fileds of the form arent submitted and thus can't be processed.